# Destroy entire AVL tree

Tags: c++, dynamic, recursion, avl-tree

I'm having a problem entirely deleting my AVL tree. I've figured out how to delete just a single node, but my `destroyTree` function doesn't seem to actually destroy every node recursively. What could I be doing wrong?

I have a struct `nodeType<myType>`

```
template <class myType>
struct nodeType {
  myType keyValue;
  int nodeHeight;
  nodeType<myType> *left;
  nodeType<myType> *right;
};
```

and I am attempted to delete all existing nodes with:

```
  if(node != NULL) {
    destroyTree(node->left);
    destroyTree(node->right);
    delete node;
  }
  node = NULL;
```

but this does not seem to properly delete the nodes, when checking for the height it still gives me the height before the destroy was called although crashes when attempting to print. In the main function calling destroy tree I used a simple if statement

```
template <class myType>
void avlTree<myType>::destroyTree()
{
  destroyTree(root);
  if(root == NULL)
    std::cout << "destroyed" << std::endl;
}
```

shows that root is NOT null (yes is not printed)

Comment: Looks good to me, but I'd recommend setting `node->left` and `node->right` to `NULL` after deleting. What makes you think the nodes aren't being deleted?

Comment: This is a method? I don't remember C++ very well, but do you have to say something like `self.destroyTree`?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart because calling my height function after calling `destroyTree` will still give me the height though it should be zero

Comment: Ah, perhaps you also need to set the node to `NULL` before deleting it? So that the height function won't just traverse through the old pointers?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose Once you `delete` a pointer, it is invalid. `NULL` is the only sensible value a pointer should have after that point. If you don't do this, how would the rest of your program know that it is using stale pointers to freed memory?

Comment: @TomZych That is wrong.

Comment: @NeilKirk Which one?

Comment: @TomZych They both are.

Comment: Code looks good, even though you got height after deletion as memory might not have been reclaimed , it might crash also.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart updated, took your advice and at least made it a little bit further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this piece of code:

```
destroyTree(root);
if(root == NULL)
    std::cout << "destroyed" << std::endl;
```

Probably your destroyTree function has this prototype:

```
void destroyTree(nodeType<myType> *node);
```

The problem is that node cant update the caller memory address, but only the contents that caller is pointing. This means that root will never be update, i.e., its contents cant be updated to NULL.

To do that, you need a prototype that is something like that:

```
void destroyTree(nodeType<myType> **node);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're not taking node **by reference**, and therefore when you set the node to `NULL` you're actually setting a **local copy** of the node to null.

**Won't work because `root` is taken by value - will have prior value after function call:**

```
template <class myType>
void avlTree<myType>::destroyTree(nodeType<myType>* node) // note node taken by value here
{
  if(node != NULL) {
    destroyTree(node->left);
    destroyTree(node->right);
    delete node;
  }
  node = NULL;
}
```

**Will work because `root` is taken by reference - will be null after the function call:**

```
template <class myType>
void avlTree<myType>::destroyTree(nodeType<myType>* &node) // note node taken by reference here
{
  if(node != NULL) {
    destroyTree(node->left);
    destroyTree(node->right);
    delete node;
  }
  node = NULL;
}
```